# error: expected identifier or '(' with C array declaration

Tags: c, gcc, syntax-error

in my header file, I have a statement to declare the MEMORY_SIZE variable.  I then want to create two arrays using the MEMORY_SIZE as the size of the array.  Here is my header file code:

```
#ifndef MEMORY_SIZE
#define MEMORY_SIZE 1024*512
#endif
```

In my main file the code im using for the buffers is:

```
//buffers
unsigned char [MEMORY_SIZE] memBytes;
unsigned char [MEMORY_SIZE] secBytes;
```

Afterwards, when I compile with gcc I get the message " error: expected identifier or '(' " for both arrays.  Also later on in the code when I try to use the array, I get " error: use of undeclared identifier 'memBytes' "

Anyone see the issue?

Comment: You should add parentheses in your macro definition: `#define MEMORY_SIZE (1024*512)`. And for extra safety, use a `L` suffix on your constants: `(1024L*512L)`, since the multiplication will overflow if `int` is 16 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're compiling Java using a C compiler.

```
unsigned char memBytes[MEMORY_SIZE];
```

<s>Grab a C book, seriously.</s> (It seems you did. In this case, drop the Java one.)

Comment: lmao my bad... I'm taking intro C at the same time as Java... whoops

Comment: @Tyler Now I understand :D (Some good advice: **do not do that.** And now I'm serious. Those two are so different languages that you will be having some serious headache, especially if you are a beginner in both.)

Comment: When I was young, I took fortran & basic the same semester (when basic still had line numbers and was limited to 2 character variable names).  I wrote a basic program with fortran variable names, the TA spotted it by asking me what fortran compiler I was using.  DOH!

Comment: oh and I do have a copy of the C programming language! thanks for the spot